# Read data from Java applet in C#

Tags: java, c#, applet

Is it possible to read data from a Java applet which can only be opened over the browser?

The applet is refreshing itself each minute (this can also be done by pressing a button) and I need to retrieve some informations which are displayed in the applet.

Comment: Instead of pulling remotely from the applet, have the applet push data to your C# webservice? Though that is some seriously questionable behaviour for an applet. Remember that anything you make accessible for yourself can be used by others too.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

Answer (score 0):

You may introduce communications between the client side applet and the server side program. We do this with a TCP socket connection from the Java applet to a Windows Service. Having Java call a web service on your server would also work.

You might alternatively interact with the applet using JavaScript and have the JS send data back to the server. To call JavaScript on the hosting page from a Java applet, call [JSObject.getWindow](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html). On the returned object, [call](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html#call(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])) calls a JavaScript method. Syntax for *call*:

```
public abstract java.lang.Object call(java.lang.String methodName,
                                      java.lang.Object[] args)
                               throws JSException
```

> Calls a JavaScript method. Equivalent to "this.methodName(args[0],
>   args[1](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html), ...)" in JavaScript.

Comment: But I can't access those applet informations with JavaScript from the outside, right? Because I don't have any possibilities to access data from inside the applet.